# How to simply upload image with web2py?

Tags: python, web2py

what I needed is just an image was upload into uploads folder as example in web2py book.
Is this only possible with SQLForm ? or what wrong with my code.Here's my code.

**model** : db.py

```
db.define_table('image',
    Field('title'),
    Field('file', 'upload'),
    format = '%(title)s')
```

in mysql image table was created title as varchar(70) file as mediumblob

**controller**

```
def index():
    image_form = FORM(
    INPUT(_name='image_title',_type='text'),
    INPUT(_name='image_file',_class='upload',_type='file')
    )
    return locals()
```

**view**

```
{{extend "layout.html"}}
{{=form}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `FORM` can do everything `SQLFORM` can do except it requires a lot more effort. `FORM` simply creates a normal html form element. `SQLFORM` does that plus builds all the controls on the form and hooks up the Submit button.

I always try to use `SQLFORM` if I can.

Your code should show a form but it won't save anything to the database. That is because you are missing the crucial `form.process` commands. It is this command that does all the hard work of validating the form and adding or updating the record.

From the [book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORM-and-uploads) and modified based on your code.

```
def index():
   record = db.image(request.args(0))  # Tries to get  an existing record where the id is specified in the first argument if the url.
   image_form = SQLFORM(db.image, record)  # Creates a form based on the 'image' table. If a record was found, it will show the record details 
   if image_form.process().accepted:  # When the form is submitted (not when it is created) it will try and process it and add the record or save any changes to the record.
       response.flash = 'form accepted' 
   elif image_form.errors:
       response.flash = 'form has errors'
   return dict(form=image_form)
```

A another problem is that you have called your form `image_form` in the controller but you are trying to display `form` in the view. My code above should work fine with your view - you can see that `image_form` is changed to `form` in the return command (`form=image_form`).